# What is the longest kidney-exchange cycle yet?

Tags: kidney, organ-transplant

What is the longest kidney-exchange cycle yet? I.e. the longest cycle of simultaneous surgeries "donor1-recipient2-donor2-recipient3 ... donorXX-recipient1"

I am preparing a lecture on the Roth-Shapley algorithm and I would like to mention the greatest success so far

Comment: Are you asking about transferring kidneys in a circle? A->B->C->D->A? I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: I'm asking about transfering kidneys in a circle {donor1, recipient1},  {donor2, recipient2} ..., when {donor1, recipient1} are, for instance , a married couple, but unfortunately immunologically incompatible. The husband is willing to give the kidney to his wife, but it is imposible. 
 One way to fix it is to search a pair with the same problem, such that donor 1 is more compatible with recipient 2, a vice versa. More complex are exchange cycles designed by nobelist Roth. But the organization is very demanding. So, I'm asking the longest cycle that has been implemented in practice so far.